# Vector of functions in Rust

Tags: rust

I am currently learning Rust and I am struggling with lifetimes while creating a simple observer that would store a callback of an arbitrary type.

I started with a basic struct

```
struct Signal<T> {
    slots: Vec<|T|>
}
```

which got me the initial lifetime error

```
signal_test.rs:7:16: 7:19 error: explicit lifetime bound required
signal_test.rs:7     slots: Vec<|T|>
                            ^~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

So next I try adding some lifetime specifiers.

```
struct Signal<'r, T> {
    slots: Vec<'r |T|>
}
```

which gets me some new errors

```
signal_test.rs:7:12: 7:23 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 0, found 1 [E0107]
signal_test.rs:7     slots: Vec<'r |T|>
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
signal_test.rs:7:19: 7:22 error: explicit lifetime bound required
signal_test.rs:7     slots: Vec<'r |T|>
```

I have not been able to find enough rust lifetime documentation to hint at what I need to do to fix this. It could just be this is not a good pattern to use in Rust. Some help and comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this:

```
struct Signal<'r, T> {
    slots: Vec<|T|: 'r>
}
```

Comment: Hey that worked! Would you mind explaining the : 'r> part of the syntax, every example I have seen puts the lifetime specifier before the type.

Comment: @EricY, that's just how closures lifetimes are specified. This is a special case. Another one is lifetime bounds of trait objects, which look like this: `Box<Trait+'a>`. You just have to get used to it :)

Comment: @EricY, current closures, however, are going to be removed in favor of unboxed closures in the nearest future, so this bit of syntax is probably going to go away completely.